# How do I get screen resolution settings to recognize hardware as capable of higher resolutions?

Tags: xubuntu, screen

I recently built a tower, and installed xubuntu from a thumbdrive. When I started it up for the first time, it came up with extremely low screen resolution, which turned out to be 640x480. When I go into the display settings to try to change it, 640x480 is the only option listed. My graphics card, according to the manufacturer, is capable of up to 7680x4320, and my monitor, up to 1920x1080 (connected via DisplayPort, which is native to both card and monitor, no adaptors involved; both monitor and card are brand new, and I don't have others to swap in to test). As far as I can tell, no error messages have been thrown. How do I get xfce to recognize the monitor's capabilities, so that I can set it to utilize them?

Video card: GeForce GTX 1650 from EVGA
Monitor: C32V1Q from AOC

Edit: In response to comments, I switched over to HDMI, and the problem still occurs on an HDMI connection, so it apparently is not a problem specific to DisplayPort.

Update: I tried installing Mint XFCE, and am still having this problem, so it is apparently not an issue with the Ubuntu-specific components.

Update: Mint was previously using the nouveau display driver from X.Org. I switched to the nvidia proprietary driver, and the situation was unchanged.

Comment: Displayport is trouble under Linux. Avoid at all cost, and attempt to connect that second monitor through hdmi or USB-C using adapter plug if needed. Chances are that issues will be gone then.

Comment: Too bad. My problem was not resolution, but poor performance, which was solved by a USB-C to HDMI convertor.

Comment: Sorry, now I see. I meant DisplayLink, which I used through a docking station, and which required a kernel driver. My bad. Sorry for the confusion: Displayport is not Displaylink indeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104540/discussion-between-matthew-najmon-and-vanadium).